# How to raise speed with PPTP?

Tags: networking, vpn, pptp

I am using pptp to access internet, I find that, the speed is about 200k/s if use pptp, the

speed is 1M/s without pptp.  so how to raise the pptp speed? thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question doesn't really make sense. PPTP and the internet are two different things. Are you saying that you're connecting to a PPTP VPN, and when you do that, your internet is dropping to 200Kbps?

What happens when you join a VPN is that the OS assumes you want to send *all* traffic over this PPTP link and sets it to be your default gateway. This means that your internet traffic goes:

`OS -> PPTP -> INTERNET -> REMOTE SITE -> (their network) -> INTERNET`

Which is kinda silly when you think about it. What you really want it:

`OS -> INTERNET` for internet traffic, and then `OS -> PPTP -> INTERNET -> REMOTE SITE` only for the subnets that are on the other side of the VPN.

You make absolutally no mention of which OS you're on, so I'm going to assume Windows. To do this on Windows, you need to:

1. Go to the properties of your PPTP connection
2. Go to TCP/IP and click on Properties
3. Go to the "Advanced" button
4. Un-check the "Use default gateway on remote network" option

If you NEED to keep all your internet traffic going over the PPTP link, then there's nothing you can do, unless you also control the remote network on the other side of the PPTP link, in which case that's a different question.

Comment: Is it possible to allows the server to control WINS but not DNS? Or does it automatically have to do both?